Defining (co)homology groups of sequential spectrum
I just started learning about spectra. I know only the following definition of the sequential spectrum. A sequential spectrum $E$ is a sequence of spaces $E_n$ with basepoint, provided with maps
$$\varepsilon_n: \Sigma E_n \longrightarrow E_{n+1}.$$
I am currently a little bit overloaded with difficult literature. I got it that we can define homotopy groups of a spectrum in this way
$$\pi_n(E) :=\lim_{\rightarrow{k}} \pi_{n+k}\left(E_k\right)$$
with respect to the maps $\pi_{n+k}\left(E_k\right)\to \pi_{n+k+1}\left(E_{k+1}\right).$
Is there a similar easy way to define homology and cohomology groups of a spectrum? Also, it would be great if someone could recommend me the easiest possible book/notes to read more on that.
Thank you.

As for a reference, Adams' Blue Book, part 3 is a standard for classical sequential spectra, and pretty fun (and not too challenging) to read, too (in my opinion).

Before talking about the (co)homology of spectra, one should understand the (co)homology theory associated to a spectrum. These definitions are given (and motivated) in section 4.F in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.
For example, the $n$th homology associated to a spectrum $E$ of a space $X$ is defined as $\pi_n(\Sigma^{\infty} X \wedge E)$ (here I'm slightly deviating from Hatcher's definition by smashing two spectra instead of a space with a spectrum). Hence if $E=\mathbb{S}$ is the sphere spectrum, we retrieve stable homotopy.
If we let $E= H\mathbb{Z}$ be the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum, we retrieve ordinary homology (see 4F.2 in Hatcher). Using this we can define the $n$th homology group of an arbitrary spectrum $F$ by $\pi_n(F \wedge H\mathbb{Z})$ (see also this wiki page).
EDIT: In the case of cohomology, Adams defines (in III.6 of the book mentioned by Ben) the $n$th $E$-cohomology group of a spectrum $F$ as $[F,E]_{-n}$, i.e. as the homotopy classes of maps of degree $-n$ from $F \to E$ (see section III.2 for the definition for maps of degree $r$). In the case $E =H\mathbb{Z}$ and the suspension spectrum $\Sigma^{\infty}X$ of a space $X$, one can use Proposition III.2.8 in the same book to deduce that $[\Sigma^{\infty}X,H\mathbb{Z}]_{-n}$ is the set of pointed homotopy classes of maps $[X, K(\mathbb{Z},n)]$. (To show this, use the $\Omega-\Sigma$ adjunction and the fact that the maps of the $\Omega$-spectrum $H\mathbb{Z}$ are homotopy equivalences, not just weak equivalences.)
This is precisely the $n$th cohomology group of $X$ by the representability of cohomology (see 4.57 in Hatcher, also the comment after 4E.1), so the definition of cohomology of spectra generalizes ordinary cohomology.

What about cohomology?

@BenSteffan Edited my answer.

Thanks! I am trying to get through all that stuff, but I expected something easier and less conceptual, to be honest. Are you saying that there is no way to define the (co)homology of a spectrum in the same manner as it is done with homotopy groups of a spectrum, i.e., by taking the (co)homology of individual spaces and taking a limit/colimit of them?

@Haldot I found this relevant question when answering yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543200/homology-of-a-spectrum

@Haldot I understand my answer is not fully satisfactory though, maybe someone else will answer, or you could try another question, perhaps on MathOverflow.

Recently I saw that this issue is also discussed in Hatcher's notes on spectral sequences, see pages 584-585 of https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch5.pdf @Haldot
